# No unity launcher and top status bar showing in Ubuntu after re-installing

Tags: unity, 14.04, lubuntu, launcher

I removed everything of Unity and Ubuntu desktop and Installed Lubuntu. But Now I want to go back to Ubuntu (Unity) and I re-installed Unity but when I login into then it doesn't show Unity launcher and Top status bar.

Did i miss anything while re-installing? How to get Unity back?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Comment: Have already tried this. but problem is still there